# boto upload "400 Bad Request" timeout

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I started with this script:

> http://zh.soup.io/post/114280923/Django-Media-on-Amazon-S3-Fabric-Deploy

I can query the bucket object for its URL, so the connection to S3 seems to work. But each time I try to upload a test file with the code

```
key.set_contents_from_file(fid)
key.set_acl('public-read')
```

I get this response (notice the `fid` printed at the top):

[image]

Any ideas? Thank you...

Comment: my guess is that it is not able to read from polar_bear.jpg. check if the file has desired permission.

Comment: Good guess, but alas, that's not the problem :/

Comment: did you figure out the issue?

Comment: No; I just tried chmod 777 (via Cygwin) and it still won't upload.

Comment: Do you have permissions to write in the bucket. Try to set permissions from was console, Everyone - write and test it again.

Comment: Didn't help, unfortunately. Screenshot of the console (after saving): http://i.imgur.com/Wus74.png

Comment: Alright man, I will try out running your code with my bucket, in couple of hours.

Comment: Thanks very much -- did you have any luck?

Comment: Its working fine with me. try to put some files in the folder where your python program is present, and put loop as -->  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()): , try , it should work

Comment: Ugh. Still not working, same error. FWIW, this is the fabfile.py I'm using, and there's a single JPG in the same directory: http://pastebin.com/hUP39WL7. I appreciate all the help you've offered, but maybe it's time to try a different option. Sux.